# Sync Framework without internet connectivity

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I have followed the developpers guide about [Transferring Data Using Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) .

When my app is connectected to internet , there is no problem , the SyncAdapter is called.

But if i'm connected to a LAN instead , the sync never happen. It is problematic for me because my app can work online and get data from a server on the web or offline , in a private network, and get data from a server on the LAN.

I can't find any mention of a mandatory internet connection in the documentation.

Should i forget the sync framework and use `AlarmManager` instead  or the sync framework can work offline ?

I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044279/syncadapter-without-internet-connection) but there is no real answer

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: nope , i'm using 4G all the time instead of closed network wifi.